# Agregar dos criterios de busqueda en sumar.si.conjunto

Tags: excel

Hola que tal buenas tardes, disculpe mi duda es como podría agregar dos criterios a un suma.si.conjunto, tengo esta formula

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$C:$C,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A:$A,"DBC2018-1",'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$B:$B,H9)
```

pero lo que me gustaría hacer es poner dos códigos para condicionar la búsqueda y me sume el tiempo de ambos códigos y me los coloque en la actividad, pensaba que la sintaxis podría ser así

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$C:$C,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A:$A,("DBC2018-1","DAP2022-1"),'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$B:$B,H9)
```

pero me sale error, también intente algo así

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$C:$C,'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A:$A,"DBC2018-1",'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$A:$A,"DAP2022-1",'[Daily time track_IU_Nov2022.xlsx]Hoja1'!$B:$B,H9)
```

pero no me suma la cantidad de horas de las actividades
Esta es la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esperaria que hiciera seria que me pusiera 1:25 en este campo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto la función SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO admite un único criterio por cada rango de criterios que selecciones. Si quieres aplicar más de 1 cuya relación sea O (es decir, sumar una columna si en otra el valor es `DBC2018-1`o `DAP2022-1`), necesitas utilizar notación matricial y trabajar con formulación matricial.

Mi ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sumar cada letra individual es fácil, es un SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO genérico:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;F3)
```

Pero si quiero juntar en la misma suma, por ejemplo A junto con C sería:

```
=SUMA(SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;{"A";"C"}))
```

La fórmula de arriba es igual a hacer dos SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO consecutivos, uno por cada criterio, es decir, es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;F3)+SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;F5)
```